# Is there a way to avoid casting for class and/or validity before using an object?

Tags: c++, class, object, c++11, unreal-engine4

I started programming on UE4 recently and find myself using this code a lot:

```
if (GetController())
{
    GetController()->GetPlayerState();
}
```

... or

```
if (GetController<APlayerController>())
{
    GetController<APlayerController>()->GetMousePosition();
}
```

The first would check if the actor has a controller and would then return its player state object.

The second would check if the actor has a controller and if that controller is the `APlayerController` class, then calls a function from the `APlayerController` class if it is. I feel like there should be a way to avoid doing this every time I want to check if an object exists or if an object is a specific class. Is there?

Comment: `std::optional<T>` for an _optional_ field.

Comment: Until c++ implements safe navigation, or until or unless that function guarantees not returning a null pointer, you’re stuck. I’m not sure how much control you have over that class, but there is a pattern to avoid having to do all these checks all the time. It’s called _the null object pattern_. The Eli5 is that if you would return a nullptr instead you return an object that exhibits no or default behavior when called.

Comment: Is there *always* a controller? Is it *always* an `APlayerController`? If an answer is no, you have to check for that *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid writing the name of the function out twice by declaring a variable in the if statement:

```cpp
// "auto"/"auto&"/"auto&&" if not a pointer type
if (auto* controller = GetController<APlayerController>()) {
    controller->GetMousePosition();
}
```

Comment: controller is gonna go poof right after it gets created.

Comment: So if I were to do that at the beginning of my logic, could I later call controller->GetMousePosition() somewhere else in the code, and if controller had failed at the beginning, it would ignore it instead of crashing?

Comment: @Taekahn `GetController` doesn't create a controller, only optionally returns a pointer to one that already exists.

Comment: @Samathan it's partially about scope. Anything inside the if statements curly braces will be able to use controller. Assuming `controller` is not deleted in the same scope, it'll always be valid in that scope.

Comment: @George yes, but `auto* controller =` _does_ create a variable. that variable will cease to exist at the end of that line. The next line tries to use the variable.

Comment: @Taekahn that's not correct. The pointer will share the lifetime of the if statement's scope. (As it would for any pointer, there's nothing special going on with this code)

Comment: @George nevermind, i was mixing up different two things.